# How can send data between distinct JSF applications?

Tags: java, http, jsf

I have two Dynamic Web Projects (JSF applications) in Eclipse.

How can I send data from one application via GET or POST HTTP requests for the other application?

Thanks

Comment: Use Apache Http Client or URLConnection or another library that handles this job, usually in your managed bean. Note that in this context, JSF will just generate HTML for your view and will handle the managed bean instances for you.

Comment: I'm also a big fan of putting such stuff in the client and use whatever javascript framework you feel comfortable with to make the requests.